# Jquery changing table th tag is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried to implement resizable table columns as follow

```
function mousemove(event) {
            var parent = $element.parent();
            var next = parent.next();
            var th = parent.parent();

            var oldParentWidth = $(parent).width();
            var oldNextWidth = $(next).width();
            var totalWidth = oldParentWidth + oldNextWidth;
            var newParentWidth = event.pageX -$(parent).offset().left;
            if( newParentWidth > totalWidth )
                return;
            if(  newParentWidth >= oldParentWidth ) {
               $(next).css({
                    width: (totalWidth - newParentWidth) + "px"
                });

                $(parent).css({
                     width: totalWidth - $(next).width() + "px"
                 });
            } else {
                $(parent).css({
                    width: newParentWidth + "px"
                });
                $(next).css({
                    width: (totalWidth - $(parent).width()) + "px"
                });

            }

        }
```

The working demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/4kc873ec/3/

When I am trying to resize the width of **th** its not working properly first time. Then after it is working correctly. After that it is working properly. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your fiddle needs to be `head` instead of `onload` what is the exact symptoms?

Comment: When I try to drag it first time, th does not set to the given css width. After that it works correctly.

Comment: You are not getting it because your mousedown is the one that assigns the event handlers. You need to assign it for ANY mousedown on the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing bind with on

```
$('.resizeBar').on('mousedown', function(event) {
               event.preventDefault();
            $element = $(this);
            $(document).on('mousemove', mousemove);
            $(document).on('mouseup', mouseup);
        });
```

Comment: I think you did not get the problem. If try to change width of on th tag, I consider the total width of current th tag and next th tag. If I try to change the width first time for the any th tag, it is not working properly.